# JavaScript replace regex with array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Trying to replace everything inside brackets [ ] with an element of an array. Example:

```
function replacingText(){
     var names = ["Cole", "Kyle", "Chase"];
     var sentance = 'This is [Cole].'
     var regex = "\[(.*?)\]/gm";
    console.log(sentance.replace(regex, names[1])); 
}
```

So the output should be 'This is Kyle.' instead of 'This is [Cole].'

Comment: Use regex syntax: `var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/;` — use a string, it's parsed as such and the backslashes will be "eaten".

Comment: I literally just tried this before I saw your comment. I feel dumb. Regret posting. Maybe someone else will see this and it'll help them though.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs fixed is the regex string needs to be

```
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/gm;
```

The /gm on the end just means it wont stop at the first one it finds and the "m" stands for multi-line matching.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript string replace can accept both strings and regular expressions as the first argument. [See the examples presented here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

In your case you are passing the first as a string of a regular expression: `"\[(.*?)\]"`

Instead you should either match the exact string `sentence.replace("[Cole]", names[1])` or, what you probably want, is to use the regular expression to match any name `sentence.replace(/\[.+\]/g, names[1])` (note that the first argument does not contain any quotes)

The /g (global) is used to match all occurrences in the sentence. Otherwise only the first occurrence would be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
function replacingText() {
  var names = ["Cole", "Kyle", "Chase"];
  var sentance = "This is [Cole] [ahmed]";
  var regex = /\[([0-9]|[aA-zZ])*\]/g;
  console.log(sentance.replace(regex, names[1]));
}
```

I just tried it and it works as expected